# Get last remaining characters if the field lenght is greater than 5

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if there is a way to select the remaining characters from the varchar field if the field length is greater than 5.

For example:

```
ID_Num

99984   
99923GF
99100EFK
99341LM
99145RL4C
```

What I am trying to get:

```
ID_Num

GF
EFK
LM
RL4C
```

Comment: If you want to select remaining characters after first 5 from the `varchar` field, then output of last row should be 6RL4C??

Comment: Not sure why somebody thought this question should be downvoted. There have been similar questions for sure but the OP provided sample data, the desired output and explained what the want to accomplish. Seems a perfectly reasonable question to me with all the details needed to answer.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped '991456RL4C', should be only 99145RL4C

Comment: It looks like you might be running into a y2k problem as your IDs are about to reach 6 digits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`STUFF` is great for things like this:

```
SELECT STUFF(ID_Num,1,5,'')
FROM YourTable
WHERE LEN(ID_Num) > 5;
```

`STUFF` is used to "replace" characters within a string. In this case, it replaces the next 5 characters from position 1 (which is the start of the string), with the string `''`; thus removing them.

Comment: get rid of where. he wants empty string if len=5.

Comment: I don't think the OP does @KeithL. There is one line break between `ID_Num` and `99984`  in their sample, but there is **not** 2 line breaks in the expected results. If they wanted a blank result, then there should be an extra (blank) line in the expected result.

Comment: either way. this is nice solution.

Comment: Of course, if they do want a blank result, hopefully they know to simply remove the `WHERE`; if not it means that don't understand `LEN`, which you would hope needs little explanation.

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was looking for. Thank you Larnu.

Answer (score 3):

Using `RIGHT` and `LEN` you can acheive your expected result.

```
SELECT RIGHT(ID_Num, LEN(ID_Num) - 5) AS ID_Num
FROM TestTable
WHERE LEN(ID_Num) > 5;
```

or using `SUBSTRING`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ID_Num, 6, LEN(ID_Num)) AS ID_Num
FROM TestTable;
```

Demo with sample data:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (ID_Num VARCHAR (20));

INSERT INTO @TestTable (ID_Num) VALUES
('99984'),
('99923GF'),
('99100EFK'),
('99341LM'),
('991456RL4C');

SELECT RIGHT(ID_Num, LEN(ID_Num) - 5) AS ID_Num
FROM @TestTable
WHERE LEN(ID_Num) > 5;
```

Output:

```
ID_Num
-------
GF
EFK
LM
6RL4C
```